# Migrating password encryption schemas

Tags: authentication, encryption, passwords, migration

I am possibly taking over an app that literally just encrypts user passwords by doing md5( password )

They have ~2000 users to date. How can I migrate those passwords to a stronger encryption schema (e.g. involving a salt, user-specific hash, and their password, all encrypted with sha1, bcrypt, whatever)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MD5 is a [cryptographic hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function), not necessarily an encryption method. A hash is designed to only be performed in one direction, and cannot be reversed other than by dictionary attack. As an example, you can try out this [hash database lookup](http://gdataonline.com/seekhash.php) if you're feeling frisky.

You will probably want to save these old passwords in a separate column, then when the users login to the "new" system, compare the MD5'ed version of that password with the old one, and if the digest matches, perform SHA1 with a salt on that password and store that in a separate column.

Alternatively, and probably a better approach, is the force the users to change passwords... and when they enter their new one, use the new hash algorithm on it instead.

Comment: thanks! i was thinking something similar - in the interest of avoiding a force the use to change their password system, i was thinking of moving the existing passwords to an additional column, as you mention, and just re-encrypting on the fly. luckily i'm dealing with 2k users vs 20k or 200k.